# Rails 4, Turbolinks, AJAX, jQuery Turbolinks: progressive lag with spinner indicator?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, turbolinks

I am trying to get a spinner and div fade to work whenever my app makes an AJAX call. It is working fine, BUT as I navigate pages throughout the app, there is a lag that starts to develop with the spinner / dim effect that keeps getting more pronounced. It ends up that the spinner / fade effect doesn't start until >1 second *after* the div in question has already refreshed.

Does anyone know how such a lag can develop by navigating pages? My Coffeescript is as follows:

```
ajax = ->
  $(document).ajaxStart ->
    $("#ajax_div").fadeTo(75, 0.55)
    $("#ajax_spinner").fadeTo(75, 1)
    return
$(document).ajaxStop ->
    $("#ajax_div").fadeTo(75, 1)
    $("#ajax_spinner").fadeTo(75, 0)
    return

$(document).ready(ajax)
$(document).on('page:load', ajax)
```

Comment: This sounds like a Javascript/jQuery issue, not a Rails issue.

Comment: Yes most likely, I wasn't sure how much Turbolinks was involved and I also wanted to establish the general context of the problem. It is very strange to see the lag grow longer the more I navigate around and trigger AJAX calls. If I stay on the same page and trigger AJAX calls the lag doesn't become apparent.